How to Add Dynamic Sliders to WordPress Customizer with JavaScript
I'm currently working on a WordPress theme where I need to add dynamic slider controls in the Customizer. My goal is to have three default slider controls and provide a button that allows adding new sliders dynamically.
However, I’m encountering a couple of issues that I need help with:

Dropdown Options Not Populating: Although I have a dropdown in the Customizer with options initially, the dropdowns in the dynamically added sliders remain empty.
New Slider Missing After Refresh: When I add a new slider using the button, it appears in the Customizer interface, but after refreshing the page, the new slider disappears. This suggests that the dynamic changes are not being saved or persisted.

here is my front-page.php:
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Front Page
*/

get_header();

// Get slider page IDs from Customizer settings
$slider_pages = array(
    get_theme_mod('set_slider_page1'),
    get_theme_mod('set_slider_page2'),
    get_theme_mod('set_slider_page3')
);

// Filter out empty values
$slider_pages = array_filter($slider_pages);
?>
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div id="frontPageSlider" class="carousel slide carousel-fade w-100" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <?php 
                $active_class = 'active';
                foreach ( $slider_pages as $page_id ) :
                    $page = get_post($page_id);
                    $featured_image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($page_id, 'full');
                    if ( $featured_image ) : ?>
                        <div class="carousel-item <?php echo $active_class; ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo esc_url($featured_image); ?>" class="d-block w-100" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($page->post_title); ?>">
                        </div>
                        <?php 
                        $active_class = '';
                    endif;
                endforeach;
                ?>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#frontPageSlider" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#frontPageSlider" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

and this is my customizer.php:
<?php 
/**
 * Kreasi Theme Customizer
 *
 * @package Kreasi
 */


 function kreasi_customizer($wp_customize) {
    // Copyright Section
    $wp_customize->add_section(
        'sec_copyright', array(
            'title'         => 'Copyright Settings',
            'description'   => 'Copyright Section'
        )
    );
    $wp_customize->add_setting(
        'set_copyright', array(
            'type'               => 'theme_mod',
            'default'            => '© [date format="Y"] Copyright - Your Company Name - All Rights Reserved',
            'sanitize_callback'  => 'sanitize_text_field'
        )
    );
    $wp_customize->add_control(
        'set_copyright', array(
            'label'         => 'Copyright',
            'description'   => 'Please, add your copyright information here',
            'section'       => 'sec_copyright',
            'type'          => 'text'
        )
    );

    // Slider Section
    $wp_customize->add_section(
        'sec_slider', array(
            'title'         => 'Slider Settings',
            'description'   => 'Slider Section'
        )
    );

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        $wp_customize->add_setting(
            'set_slider_page' . $i, array(
                'type'               => 'theme_mod',
                'default'            => '',
                'sanitize_callback'  => 'absint'
            )
        );
        $wp_customize->add_control(
            'set_slider_page' . $i, array(
                'label'         => 'Set slider page ' . $i,
                'description'   => 'Set slider page ' . $i,
                'section'       => 'sec_slider',
                'type'          => 'dropdown-pages'
            )
        );
    }

    $wp_customize->add_setting(
        'set_slider_button', array(
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field'
        )
    );

    $wp_customize->add_control(
        'set_slider_button', array(
            'type'       => 'button',
            'settings' => array(),
            'section'    => 'sec_slider',
            'input_attrs' => array(
                'value' => 'Add New Slider',
                'class' => 'button button-primary add-slider-button'
            ),
        )
    );
}
add_action('customize_register', 'kreasi_customizer');


?>

last, this is my customizer.js:
import $ from 'jquery';

class jsCustomizer {
    constructor() {
        this.events();
    }

    events() {
        $(document).ready(() => {
            if (ajaxdata.is_admin) {
                this.addSliderButton();
            }
        });
    }

    addSliderButton() {
        // Event handler untuk tombol
        $(document).on('click', '.add-slider-button', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.addNewSlider();
        });
    }

    addNewSlider() {
        // Mendapatkan jumlah slider yang sudah ada
        const existingSliders = $('[id^=customize-control-set_slider_page]').length;
        const newSliderIndex = existingSliders + 1;

        // Mengambil HTML dari dropdown pertama untuk mendapatkan opsi
        const dropdownHtml = $('#set_slider_page1').html();

        // Membuat elemen kontrol slider baru
        const newControlHtml = `
            <div id="customize-control-set_slider_page${newSliderIndex}" class="customize-control customize-control-dropdown-pages">
                <label>
                    <span class="customize-control-title">Set slider page ${newSliderIndex}</span>
                </label>
                <select id="set_slider_page${newSliderIndex}" name="set_slider_page${newSliderIndex}" class="customize-control-dropdown-pages">
                    ${dropdownHtml}
                </select>
            </div>
        `;

        // Menambahkan kontrol slider baru ke section slider
        $('#sub-accordion-section-sec_slider').append(newControlHtml);

        // Trigger update to add the new control to the Customizer
        wp.customize.previewer.refresh();
    }
}

export default jsCustomizer;

Thank you in advance.
